# Parsing in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have to parse the following

```
/*-secure- {"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"3mva6l4ph7816571thcnc391vj"‌​}}}*/
```

and extract 3mva6l4ph7816571thcnc391vj

Comment: Consider using a JSON parser like [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) where the text is preprocessed with another tool that removes other unnecessary string. Also consider using another language like Ruby.

Comment: @konsolebox ok, I'm trying using jq. Can you validate if it is correct? FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('type response.txt ^| jq .challenges.wl_antiXSRFRealm.WL-Instance-Id') DO echo %%G

Comment: I can't test it that way. What are the fields `.challenges.wl_antiXSRFRealm.WL-Instance-Id`? You should at least provide contents from `response.txt`.

Comment: /*-secure-
{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"3mva6l4ph7816571thcnc391vj"}}}*/

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25350816/edit) your question to provide additional information. Do not attempt to post code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f usebackq^ tokens^=8^ delims^=^" %%a in ("response.txt") do echo %%a
```

Use the quote as delimiter and get the required field

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('find /i "child2" test.txt') do (
  set a=%%i
  set a=!a:*child2":"=!
  set a=!a:"}}}*/=!
)
echo %a%
```

`set a=!a:*child2":"=!` removes all from beginning of the line including `child2":"`

`set a=!a:"}}}*/=!` removes the string `"}}}*/` at the end

Answer (score 0):

With a cleaned input like this:

```
{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"3mva6l4ph7816571thcnc391vj"}}}
```

This should work:

```
jq -r .challenges.wl_antiXSRFRealm."WL-Instance-Id" response.txt
```

Output:

```
3mva6l4ph7816571thcnc391vj
```